# Android Camera2 Image Processing: What is Geometric Correction?

Tags: android, hal, camera2

On [this](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/camera3_requests_hal.html) page, there is a picture of the camera pipeline (Figure 2). It says, there are eight stages during Image Processing.
I found the stages with corresponding names in the CameraMetadata, except for one stage:

Geometric Correction

I have googled for it, but found no information in relation to Android...
So what does it do in Android? And how can I access/configure it?

Comment: Your search didn't find this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_geometry_correction

Comment: I see that I did not specify the question correctly. I meant: What does it do in Android? And how to implement it?
But thank you nevertheless for the link^^

Comment: From your original link: "Please note, some image processing blocks shown in the diagram above are not well-defined in the initial release.". My guess is that its for lens geometry correction which would be device/camera specific. This link has some sample pictures at bottom http://graphics.stanford.edu/~dzorin/perception/sig95/ for correcting a wide-angle lens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometric correction didn't make it into the initial release of the camera2 API, but not all the diagrams were updated accordingly.

Comment: How do you know? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I wrote most of the API.